# ADF lookup to Foreach

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have json input file and using lookup activity and passing to Foreach to get file name list.
But I am facing issue in foreach activity and get the file list.

Input Json:

```
> {
>     "ItemsCount": 2,
>     "FilteredItemsCount": 1,
>     "Value": [
>         {
>             "Sourcetype": "DB",
>             "DB": "test",
>             "Filename": [
>                 "dbo.Emp",
>                 "dbo.Emp1"
>             ]
>         }
>     ] }
```

Foreach setting:

```
@activity('Filter2').output.Filename
```

```
Error
{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'length(activity('Filter2').output.Filename)' cannot be evaluated because property 'Filename' doesn't exist, available properties are 'ItemsCount, FilteredItemsCount, Value'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy_DB_to_DataLake",
    "details": ""
}
```

Kindly confirm my foreach setting and let me know if anything needs to add.

Thanks.

Comment: what you are filtering from lookup output?  can you elaborate mor what you are trying?

Comment: try `@activity('Filter2').output.value[0].Filename` As your value array have multiple items it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach requires an array. To loop over the results of a Filter, you need to reference the 'value' property:

```
@activity('Filter2').output.value
```

Then inside your loop, each iteration can be referenced by using "@item()" as the root object:

```
@item().Filename
```